# 31 days on the highcharts x-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a graph that i am plotting but i need to show 31 days of the month on the x-axis.

If you look at this  http://jsfiddle.net/codebreaker87/7hq6ueeb/2/show/

it only shows 31 days but the 31st is missing.  This is the code

http://jsfiddle.net/codebreaker87/7hq6ueeb/6/

How can i have the 31st day displayed?.

This is my code so far

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'SMS Volumes'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Textify'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12','13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Volumes(1000)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Inbox',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6,7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6,7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5]
    }, {
        name: 'Outbox',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8,3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8,3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2]
    }]
});
```

Comment: hey, you have only 30 item in data box, just add +1 value

Comment: Thanks sir. I have corrected it http://jsfiddle.net/codebreaker87/7hq6ueeb/7/show/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only add point to 31 element:-

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line',
       
       
    },
    title: {
        text: 'SMS Volumes'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Textify'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12','13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31'],
      

    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Volumes(1000)'
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            enableMouseTracking: false
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Inbox',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6,7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6,7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5,21.6]
    }, {
        name: 'Outbox',
        data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8,3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8,3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2,15.3]
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set *xAxis.max* value as 30 (categories are indexed from 0).

```
xAxis: {
    categories: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12','13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24','25','26','27','28','29','30','31'],
    max: 30
},
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/psnjdo4o/